# Using python for google calendar watch-requests

Tags: python, webhooks, watch, google-calendar-api

I want to set up a watch request for a google calendar, using python 
(without setting up a separate domain).

1. I imported the api client, and can successfully get the authenticated credentials, following the example: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/python.
2. Then I set up a calendar service, and I am able to list, insert and delete events without any issue.

The problem I am having is when I perform a watch request so that I have a webhook from within python. 
I receive the error: 
"googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events/watch?alt=json returned "WebHook callback must be HTTPS:">"

Clearly I am missing something that needs to be setup so that calendar is satisfied with the webhook I am giving it. 
Is it possible to do this from within python, without setting up a separate domain with https, and if so, how?

Minimum working example:

---

```
import httplib2
import os
from apiclient import discovery
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.file import Storage
import uuid

try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Calendar API'


def get_credentials():

    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')

    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                                   'calendar-api.json')

    store = Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()

    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        else: 
            credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
        print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
    return credentials


def main():

    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('calendar', 'v3', http=http)


## TESTING callback receiver: 
    eventcollect = {
        'id': str(uuid.uuid1()),
        'type': "web_hook"
    }

    service.events().watch(calendarId='primary', body=eventcollect).execute()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the documentation of [watch requests](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push), there is a `Required Properties` part. In this part it is clearly stated that:

- An `address` property string set to the URL that listens and responds to notifications for this notification channel. **This is your Webhook callback URL, and it must use HTTPS**.

I am sorry but I do not think there is a workaround for this.

Comment: Ok thanks, I understand. I was just wondering if one could set up a self-signed https as a localhost with a URL that would be sufficient as a webhook to point to in the JSON variable posted to watch().